# Splitting polygon between its neighbor polygons with Voronoi algorithm using Python

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, shapely, voronoi-thiessen

I would like to split the area of my concerned polygon (the blue one in the middle) between his neighbors polygons and affect each splitted area to a neighbor

[image: See picture]

My data looks like:

| affectid | t | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 27 | concerned | POLYGON ((598298.993 2436032.831, 598294.993 2.. |
| 27 | neighboors | POLYGON ((598090.693 2436754.332, 598312.993 2... |
| 27 | neighboors | POLYGON ((598125.793 2436752.332, 598217.893 2... |
| 27 | neighboors | POLYGON ((598500.094 2436244.031, 598465.993 2... |
| 27 | neighboors | POLYGON ((598298.993 2436032.831, 598294.993 2.. |

How I can do it using Voronoi algorithm in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.ops import voronoi_diagram
from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint

df = gpd.read_file(r"C:/GIS/GIStest/split.shp")
df2 = df.loc[df["t"]=="concerned"].copy() #Extract the polygons with concerned attribute

#Create the column voronois, which is a list of voronoi polygons
df2["voronois"] = df2.apply(lambda x: list(voronoi_diagram(geom=MultiPoint([Point(*c) for c in x.geometry.exterior.coords]), envelope=x["geometry"]).geoms), axis=1)
df2 = df2.explode("voronois") #From list to rows
#Clip the voronois by geometry
df2["geometry"] = df2.apply(lambda x: x.voronois.intersection(x.geometry), axis=1)
del(df2["voronois"])
result = gpd.pd.concat([df.loc[df["t"]!="concerned"], df2])
result.to_file(r"C:/GIS/GIStest/split_voronoi.shp")
```

[image]

Comment: The solution works well (the polygon is splited into multiple ones)
So how I do affect each new polygon to the neighbors ?

Comment: Script might work, but split shown is wrong. You need to density lines

Comment: Any code example to density lines ?

Comment: `df2["geometry"] = df2.apply(lambda x: x.geometry.segmentize(segment_length), axis=1)`